# Create numbering in a column in excel that updates automatically but skips if there is an empty value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet in the following format and I would like to create numbering that updates itself whenever a new row with information is added which could be both at the end of the sheet or could also be a line that is inserted in the middle of the sheet.

Basically I want there only to be a number in column A if column B is not empty.

[image]

I have used =IF(ISEMPTY(B18)," ",A15+1) to find the value for A18, but I'm not sure how to expand that to the rest of the sheet. Instead of A15, I would probably need to look for the previous non-empty value, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any suggestions? Also, if there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
=IF(A2="","","Variable " & COUNTA($A$2:$A2))
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Also, I want the fields that have Test, Hello and Excel in your answer to have numbers too.

Comment: I think it will be reverse. You need to enter the formula in cell `A2` `=IF(B2="","",MAX($A$1:A1)+1)`

Comment: @Harun24hr dada op needs the one in `Column A` and not in `Column B`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya If so, then I have misunderstood.

Comment: also there is no function called `ISEMPTY()` unless its `UDF`

Comment: How then `A2` result is `3`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A2`

```
=IF(B2="","",MAX($A$1:A1)+1)
```

---

Or,

```
=IF(B2="","",SUBTOTAL(3,B$2:B2))
```

---

With `BYROW()`

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(B2:B19,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,B2,IF(x="","",COUNTIF(y:x,"<>")))))
```

---

Comment: Thank you, this works for me in Google sheets, but not in Excel. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: But i have shown using `Excel` not sure about `Google-Sheets` can you show how it is not working

Comment: Ok, this is very strange then... I get #NAME? in the cell instead of a number when I paste it in Excel.

Comment: **[#NAME?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-name-error-b6d54e31-a743-4d7d-9b61-40002a7b4286)** error occurs only when the function is not available in your version of `Excel` or you have done some typos. Please check at your end

Comment: It works in Excel when I download it from Google sheets

Comment: Ok found the problem. My cells in excel were locked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Excel cells are locked by default. are you referring sheet protection?

Comment: @rtzu please ensure to check the tick mark beside the answer since the solution has worked for you.